# How to store crash log file inside the ios application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, crash-reports

suppose my application was crashed means at that time `applicationWillTerminate` function is called. In that function i want to save the crash log file in the Temporary directory.
when app is launch at that time I want to upload the crash report file from the iOS device to my server location  thorough the coding.

I'm using this code to save the crash log file.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console.log"];
freopen([logPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
```

but this code will work in the simulator. i can able to see this file in

```
/Users/UserNAme/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/xxx-yyy-sss--eee/Documents/console.log
```

but i can't find this file in the ios devices.

Note:
for finding file in the ios device I'm using `iExplorer`

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, you cannot get at the crashlog on the device programmatically.   To overcome this, there are a number of commercial, quasi-commercial, and open source solutions.

In particular, [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net) (owned by Microsoft now) and [crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/) provide commercial solutions. In addition, [TestFlightApp](http://testflightapp.com) (although purchased by Apple) still provides this kind of functionality through its interface.

The HockeyApp source code is also available on [github](https://github.com/bitstadium).

In the end, most of these system use an underlying crash catcher called [plcrashreporter](https://plcrashreporter.org) which is an open-source framework which places a near-exact copy of the iOS Crash Report in your directory.

If you want to manage things yourself, I'd strongly suggest `plcrashreporter`, otherwise the hosted and commercial solutions are available and you should look at them and decide yourself.

Comment: of-course am using this application TestFlightApp for deveoper,s and tester's testing purpose. Here I want send that crash file to specific mail id only.

Comment: The answers above are still on-point.   If you need to handle the crash report yourself, you're going to have to generate it yourself.   There is absolutely no way to break out of the sandbox and grab the OS version of the crash report from within the device.   The only other option is to grab it off of the device manually, or using iTunes or Xcode, but I get the impression you're looking to do this for field-placed devices, not development ones.   Also, most of the hosted solutions can be used with live as well as test apps.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful option (we use it) is Crashlytics.com, which is free and has a lot of control over the reporting (owned by twitter now, use with caution!).